# How to make `aws s3 sync` ignore size and only use last modified time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to make `aws s3 sync` only use **last modified time**?
i.e., even if file sizes differ, only copy if source is newer than destination

If not, is there an easy workaround to get this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: There is no native capability in the AWS CLI to do this. The only option is `--size-only`, which makes the size of each key the only criteria used to decide whether to sync from source to destination.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, do you happen to know any other unofficial tools that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If this sync operation is from local folder to S3 destination, you can use a combination of git and S3 Sync CLI's "include" and "exclude" options to accomplish this

For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

FILES=()
for i in $( git status -s | sed 's/\s*[a-zA-Z?]\+ \(.*\)/\1/' ); do
    FILES+=( "$i" )
done
#echo "${FILES[@]}"

CMDS=()
for i in "${FILES[@]}"; do
    CMDS+=("--include=$i""*")
done
#echo "${CMDS[@]}"

echo "${CMDS[@]}" | xargs aws s3 sync . s3://dest.com [-otherflags]"*"
```

Comment: There is no git.